# How to add hover colour to a div which has linear gradient Border?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am trying to add hover color to this particular div but it dosen't work out, because of the gradient background that is added to get the border-radius working.

I am doing this in a React Component using css-modules .

What is the problem here? I am not an expert at css but will love to know the reason of the problem and how to mitigate it .

```css
.card{
  width: 40%;
  height: 150px;
  border: 2px solid transparent;
  background:
    linear-gradient(#fff,#fff) padding-box,
    linear-gradient(125deg, #42E4A3, #A383E8) border-box;
  border-radius:8px;
  display:inline-block;
}

.card:hover{
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.04);
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  No Hover color red <br/>
  I am doing this in React a small gist of the problem
</div>
```

**Update**

After adding the styles as mentioned i get the opposite effect where the border gradient color appears on hover .If i add this i get the color but the b order color then disappears.

The gradient dosen't accept rgba with such low opacity for some reason , what is the reason for this

```
.card:hover{
  background:
    linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.04),rgba(0,0,0,0.04)) padding-box;
} // no border color , when i change the color to rgba opacity it dosent work
```

> rgba(0,0,0,0.1) works but why not rgba(0,0,0,0.04)

Answer (score 2):

You can fix it like that:

```
.card:hover{
  background: red;
}
```

and it will work =)

or, if you want to keep your gradient border:

```
.card:hover{
      background: linear-gradient(red,red) padding-box, 
                  linear-gradient(125deg, #42E4A3, #A383E8) border-box;
    }
```

If you need a semitransparent color of background, you can re-edit your solution like this ([demo on Codepen](https://codepen.io/nat-davydova/pen/a24f540307ab76c0a041a8d165fea2c6)). But anyway you will see on hover bottom background because of semitransparency.

Comment: thanks for such a quick response, but when i add the following the gradient color green and purple comes in the hover color ? i am not quite sure what i am messing up

Comment: i got the reason when the change the color to rgba it dosen't work any reason for this ?

Comment: please add this line `linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.04),rgba(0,0,0,0.04)) padding-box,` instead of red and you will get to see the problem

Comment: @RahulSingh look, you have 2 gradients here, both applied to one element, so if you use semitransparent colors for background on hover, gradient at the bottom will be visible. Let me edit my answer, I have a solution

Comment: @RahulSingh check please edited answer, if you have any questions, let me know

Answer (score 2):

In your `:hover` style you should redefine the `background` property with the border gradient, just simply replace the white color `#fff` with your new color `red`

```css
.card{
  width: 40%;
  height: 150px;
  border: 2px solid transparent;
  background:
    linear-gradient(#fff,#fff) padding-box,
    linear-gradient(125deg, #42E4A3, #A383E8) border-box;
  border-radius:8px;
  display:inline-block;
}

.card:hover{
  background:
    linear-gradient(red,red) padding-box,
    linear-gradient(125deg, #42E4A3, #A383E8) border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  No Hover color red <br/>
  I am doing this in React a small gist of the problem
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for such a quick response, but when i add the following the gradient color green and purple comes in the hover color ? i am not quite sure what i am messing up

Comment: i got the reason when the change the color to rgba it dosen't work any reason for this ?

Comment: please add this line `linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.04),rgba(0,0,0,0.04)) padding-box,` instead of red and you will get to see the problem

Comment: Yes if it has any bit of transparency you will see the other "border" gradient. The problem is how you are implementing the fake border with the `background` style. You should separate the border style from the background style by using the CSS [border-image](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-image) property for the border and `background` for just the background, then you will have more control